# state issue when clicking between different divs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-state

I am having an issue with my application's state tracking. I have an edit form, and when I click on a ticket to set it as the selected ticket, I pass the selected ticket down to the edit form. However, I think I have an issue with the way my state is being tracked.

I believe the exact issue is here:

```
function handleClick(ticket) {
        setSelectedTicket(ticket);
      }
```

If I edit a ticket then click on any other tickets, the updated info then gets passed to all the other tickets.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import TicketDetails from "./TicketDetails";

const Container = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
`;

const Gradient = styled.div`
  background: black;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 96%;
`;

const H2 = styled.h2`
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
`;

const TicketContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
`;

const TicketList = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 38vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 50%;
`;

const Ticket = styled.div`
  margin-right: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const DetailsContainer = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto auto auto;
  width: 300px;
`;

const MyTickets = ({ user }) => {
  const [tickets, setTickets] = useState([]);
  const [selectedTicket, setSelectedTicket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/users/${user.id}`)
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.tickets.length > 25) {
          setTickets(data.tickets.slice(0, 25));
        } else {
          setTickets(data.tickets);
        }
      });
  }, []);

  function refreshTickets() {
    fetch(`/users/${user.id}`)
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.tickets.length > 25) {
          setTickets(data.tickets.slice(0, 25));
        } else {
          setTickets(data.tickets);
        }
      });
  }

  function limitChars(string) {
    if (string.length > 18) {
      return string.slice(0, 18) + "...";
    }
    return string;
  }

  function handleClick(ticket) {
    setSelectedTicket(ticket);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg"></div>
      <div className="bg bg2"></div>
      <div className="bg bg3"></div>
      <Container>
        <H2>{user.username}'s tickets</H2>
        <Gradient></Gradient>
        <TicketContainer>
          <TicketList>
            {tickets.map((ticket, index) => {
              return (
                <Ticket key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(ticket)}>
                  {index + 1}: {limitChars(ticket.title)}
                </Ticket>
              );
            })}
          </TicketList>
          <DetailsContainer>
            {selectedTicket ? (
              <TicketDetails
                ticket={selectedTicket}
                refreshTickets={refreshTickets}
              />
            ) : (
              <div>Select a ticket</div>
            )}
          </DetailsContainer>
        </TicketContainer>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyTickets;
```

Below is how I update the ticket:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
`;

const Title = styled.div`
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0.5rem;
`;

const Gradient = styled.div`
  background: black;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0.5rem;
`;

const Description = styled.div`
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  margin: 0.5rem;
`;

const ContentContainer = styled.div`
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
`;

const TextArea = styled.textarea`
  height: 100px;
  width: 98%;
  padding: 1%;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
`;

const ButtonContainer = styled.div`
  flex-direction: row;
`;

const EditButton = styled.button`
  width: 5rem;
`;

const categories = [
  "URGENT",
  "Meetings",
  "To Do",
  "In Progress",
  "Needs Review",
];

const Category = styled.div`
  margin: 0.5rem;
`;

const TicketDetails = ({ ticket, refreshTickets }) => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(ticket.title);
  const [initialTitle, setInitialTitle] = useState(ticket.title);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(ticket.description);
  const [descriptionInit, setDescriptionInit] = useState(ticket.description);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(`/tickets/${ticket.id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: title, description: description }),
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((d) => {
        console.log("updated ticket", d);
        setTitle(d.title);
        setDescription(d.description);
        refreshTickets();
      });
    setEdit(false);
  };

  const handleReset = (e) => {
    setTitle(initialTitle);
    setDescription(descriptionInit);
  };

  const handleCancel = (e) => {
    setTitle(initialTitle);
    setDescription(descriptionInit);
    setEdit(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Category>{categories[ticket.category_id - 1]}</Category>
      <Gradient></Gradient>
      {edit ? (
        <Container
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#B1D4E0",
          }}
        >
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} onReset={handleReset}>
            <Input
              type="text"
              id="title"
              autoComplete="off"
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Gradient></Gradient>
            <TextArea
              type="text"
              id="description"
              autoComplete="off"
              value={description}
              onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
            />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
            <button onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
          </form>
        </Container>
      ) : (
        <Container
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#B1D4E0",
          }}
        >
          <Title>{ticket.title}</Title>
          <Gradient></Gradient>
          <ContentContainer>
            <Description>{ticket.description}</Description>
          </ContentContainer>
          <ButtonContainer>
            <EditButton onClick={() => setEdit(true)}>Edit</EditButton>
          </ButtonContainer>
        </Container>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default TicketDetails;
```

Comment: How do u update the ticket?

Comment: I am going to add the update ticket to the original post, its too long to comment

Answer (score 0):

I think that the info updated is kept because the component is always mount, you change the `ticket` value in props but this does not re-initialize your state in `TicketDetails`. To update the values when other ticket is selected add a `useEffect` like this:

```
const TicketDetails = ({ ticket, refreshTickets }) => {
  //...
  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(ticket.title);
    setInitialTitle(ticket.title);
    setDescription(ticket.description);
    setDescriptionInit(ticket.description);
  }, [ticket]);
```